# Spring-Data-JPA Specification with Aggregate function

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, specifications

How can we write below query using Specification

```
SELECT e.id, e.name, count(e.id) 
FROM Employee e INNER JOIN Department d
WHERE e.id = d.empId;
```

When we are using Specification, it is not selecting count() even it is mentioned in multiselect.

Any idea, how to include count column in Specification when we are using JPA **findAll** method.

Tried with multiselect, but when it passed to specification then it query only on non-aggregated columns.

```
Expression<Long> countExp = cb.count(root.get("id"));
 CriteriaQuery<Employee> select =
 criteriaQuery.multiselect(root.get("id"), root.get("name"), countExp);
```

But it generates query like :

```
SELECT e.id, e.name
FROM Employee e INNER JOIN Department d
WHERE e.id = d.empId;
```

Seems having same issue as: 
[JpaSpecificationExecutor : complex queries with specifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14204841/jpaspecificationexecutor-complex-queries-with-specifications)

[Why the multiselect method in JPA does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28852670/why-the-multiselect-method-in-jpa-does-not-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve above problem, created own JPARepository implementation and override getQuery method from SimpleJpaRepository

```
private TypedQuery<Employee> getQuery(Specification<Employee> spec, Sort sort) {
        CriteriaBuilder builder = this.em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Employee> query = builder.createQuery(Employee.class);
        Root<Employee> root = this.applySpecificationToCriteria(spec, query);

        query.multiselect(root.get("id"), root.get("name"),
                builder.count(root.get("id")).alias("count"));

        if (sort != null) {
            query.orderBy(QueryUtils.toOrders(sort, root, builder));
        }

        return this.em.createQuery(query);
    }
```

Comment: I'm using spring boot 1.5.22 and at least in this version the method applySpecificationToCriteria is private, so I can't use it.